# Infinite loop when using scanf

Tags: c, client-server

I am writing a C program that consists of a client and server communicating. In the client file, I use `scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-z ]", message);` (accept numbers, letters and space) to scan for inputs from the user to send to the server, however I am getting an infinite loop. Below is the portion of code where this is used:

```
 while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter message : ");
        scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-z ]", message); 

    if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
        break;
    }

    puts("Server reply :");
    //printf("\nServer reply : %s " ,server_reply);
    puts(server_reply);
}
exit(0); 
close(sock);
```

The output consists of the "Enter message" and "server reply" consecutively.

Comment: `"%79[0-9a-zA-z ]"` : Since non-accepted characters are not accepted, newline  are rejected in the next loop. It is necessary to clear such unacceptable letters before next loop.

Comment: are you saying I should accept new lines? so it looks like %79[0-9a-zA-z\n ] ?

Comment: No. E.g `"%79[0-9a-zA-z ]%*c"` `%*c` consume one character (When it ends with a newline). Also, it is necessary to clear the input buffer not only in case of normal input but also in case of actually illegal characters.

Comment: E.g `char ch;...if(2 != scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-z ]%c", message, &ch) || ch != '\n'){ /* invalid input */ while(getchar()!='\n'); } else { /* valid input */ ...; }`

Comment: The usual way is using something like `char c; do c=getchar() while(c!= '\n' && c!=EOF);` after your scanf() call.

Comment: @NomeQueEuLembro `char c;` --> `int c;` for `c!=EOF`

Comment: My mistake! You're right.

Comment: @samgak: I don't see a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code needs to consume the new line [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739667/infinite-loop-when-using-scanf#comment72597208_42739667)

```
while(1) {
    printf("Enter message : ");
    scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-z ]", message); 

    // Now the \n needs to be read
    int ch = fgetc(stdin);
    ...
}
```

Better code would add checks

```
while(1) {
    printf("Enter message : ");
    fflush(stdout); // insure potentially buffered data is outputted

    if (scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-z ]", message) != 1) {
      puts("Nothing read");
      break;
    }

    int ch = fgetc(stdin);
    if (ch == `'\n') {
      ; // good: new line
    } else if (ch == EOF) {
      break; // no more input or input error
    } else {
      puts("Unexpected input");
      break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Even better code would use `fgets()`

```
char buf[81];
while (1) {
    printf("Enter message : ");
    fflush(stdout);

    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) break;
    char ch;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%79[0-9a-zA-z ] %c", message, &ch) != 1) {
      puts("Nothing or too much read");
      break;
    } 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-z ]", &message);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-z ]", message);
```